# Why shouldn't INFORMATION_SCHEMA views be used to determine the schema of an object?

Tags: sql-server, schema, sql-server-2017, metadata, information-schema

According to MS-DOCS about [System information schema views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the schema [columns definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/constraint-column-usage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) have a warning note that says:

> ** **Important** ** Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a
>   object is to query the sys.objects catalog view.

Why can't INFORMATION_SCHEMA views be used to determine the schema of an object?

Is this information erroneous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the statement there is inaccurate. I talk about this in [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) (and complained about it [in this ancient Connect item](http://web.archive.org/web/20121126175858/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/686118/doc-information-schema-tables-gives-improper-warning-about-schema)), where I implore people to use the `sys` catalog views over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

> The warning really should state that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are incomplete; the wording above implies that they might be incorrect, which in itself is incorrect.

In 2011, they said:

> Hi Aaron,
>   That particular wording has been in the topic since 2005. But, I see your point. We'll revist the wording and try to make it more clear.

Now that we can submit pull requests for suggested changes to the documentation, it might be time for someone to make them pay attention to it again. 13 years is long enough.

Comment: Perhaps the wording is from the pre-2005 days when we didn't have the schema concept the way we do today? I think, for instance, that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA returned one row *per database* in those days. I do agree, it is way overdue to change that wording. The fact that MS can't be bothered is IMO yet another sign that they do not pay much attention (at all) to these views since the birth of the catalog views.